# Freshdesk Sample Payload array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, freshdesk

I had this code that works if simple string is called

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    app.initialized()
        .then(function(_client) {
          var client = _client;
          client.events.on('app.activated',
            function() {
                client.data.get('ticket')
                    .then(function(data) {
                        $('#issue_title').text("Issue:" + data.ticket.description);
                    })
                    .catch(function(e) {
                        console.log('Exception - ', e);
                    });
        });
    });
});
```

But when I change it to array object it doesnt work

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    app.initialized()
        .then(function(_client) {
          var client = _client;
          client.events.on('app.activated',
            function() {
                client.data.get('ticket')
                    .then(function(data) {
                        $('#issue_title').text("Issue:" + data.ticket.attachments['name']);
                    })
                    .catch(function(e) {
                        console.log('Exception - ', e);
                    });
        });
    });
});
```

Im using this ticket ATTACHMENTS payload

```
Sample Payload

{
  "ticket": {
    "attachments": [],
    "cc_emails": [],
    "company_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T06:05:56.000Z",
    "custom_fields": [{
      "custom_number": null,
      "custom_line1": " "
    }],
}
```

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://developer.freshdesk.com/api/#create_ticket_with_attachment), the attachments are returned as array of object. So, it should be accessed with the index. If the array is empty, it won't return anything so the empty array should be handled.

If your issue is different, could you attach what is the error while accessing the attachment name?

Answer (score 0):

if you could share the value of the array that would be awesome.

For now you are trying to navigate an Array as if it were an object, Array's are index based and don't have keys :)

If you can update the payload as such

```
{
  "ticket": {
    "attachments": {
       name: "",
    },
    "cc_emails": [],
    "company_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T06:05:56.000Z",
    "custom_fields": [{
      "custom_number": null,
      "custom_line1": " "
    }],
}
```

Otherwise i'm not sure how you are anticipating the array to return your value.

If it is an array with the structure [key, value, key, value] you can go

```
data.ticket.attachments[data.ticket.attachments.indexOf('name') + 1]
```

Finally if it's an array of objects you can go

```
data.ticket.attachments.find(attachment => attachment.key === 
'name').YourKey
```